# Is it appropriate to speak formally to everyone?

Tags: american-english, formality

I was reading online something about formal English because right now I'm learning formal English. They say speaking formally to anyone will get you far in life because it shows respect and politeness. Is this true? Sorry if this looks like a stupid question. :(

Comment: It's not stupid. There seems to a lot of questions about formal English. What do you mean by the term? Can you give us some examples?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This appears to be a cultural question rather than a question about the language itself. It's also not really clear what you mean by "formal English" -- as opposed to what? One can be **polite** using the Cockney *mate, bruv, me ol' China,* but it's hardly formal. And in some circumstances, that slang is exactly the right thing to use rather than formal English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach We are getting a lot of questions about this. Learners are obviously concerned about their use of English. It needs to be addressed in my opinion, if only in ELL meta.

Comment: Define *appropriate*. Primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Whatever your opinion about Donald Trump, it is clear that he has never relied on a "formal" speaking style to get where he is. "Getting far in life" often depends on satisfying a particular demographic. Popular magazines rely on a more colloquial style than do research papers--this is to ensure their continued popularity. "Proper" English--using "whom" for example--can open doors if the person you're speaking to values that, but some people view such things as stilted and elitist. To get far, you need to know your audience and speak to them in a way that they can relate to.

Comment: It depends on your relationship with the audience and the type of situation. If they aren't formal or serious, it's unnecessary. Though, I feel learning colloquialism is detrimental and largely pointless. As an ELL, you want to maximize your proficiency in English. Learning colloquialism delays this. E.g. yes. The colloquial synonyms are yep, yeah, ye, yeh ect. It takes more time to learn these exact synonyms. By learning colloquialism, you also risk having it leak into formal writing or conversation. Non-colloquial language will never be inappropriate or reproached. It is omni-applicable.

Answer (score 5):

English has no distinction between second person singular (informal in some languages) or plural (formal in some languages). We use "you" for both.

It is also somewhat egalitarian, in that there are no honorifics that change a verb or noun when the speaker and the hearer have a greater social distance.

English has no way to change a noun to become more formal, such as the Korean -nim suffix.

> Seonsaeng-nim, commonly translated as "teacher"

(The above example is from a Wikipedia article on [Korean Honorifics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_honorifics).)

There are no formal forms to address another, such as the French [vouvoyer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vouvoyer). (This is using a more formal "vous" to address someone instead of an informal "tu." Sorry to cite a French page, but there's no equivalent word in English, for good reason.)

In short, there's no way to learn "formal" English, because English has divested itself of formality. You could say to either a child or a king: "Please sit here."

However, English (and probably all languages) has different *registers*. The [Wikipedia article on Register (sociolinguistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)) lists these registers, which indicate different levels of formality:

> - bench-level register
> - dialect register
> - facetious register
> - formal register
> - in house register
> - ironic register
> - neutral register
> - slang register
> - taboo register
> - technical register
> - vulgar register

So you could say to a child, "Sit here." And with a more formal register, you could ask a king, "Would your highness wish to be seated here?" (While the latter sentence uses more indirection, neither its nouns nor its verbs are inflected to indicate formality.)

While the more formal registers may be associated with politeness, I can't say with certainty that they will get you further in life.

If you addressed a friend as *your highness*, it would not be perceived as more formal speech, but rather as ironic.